# может ли функция выполнять несколько операций?

Tags: javascript

```
function hideShadow(){
    var el = document.getElementById("shadow");
    el.style.boxShadow = "0 0 0 0";

    var elText = document.getElementById("shadow");
    elText.style.textShadow = "0 0 0 0";
}
```

Comment: Это один из тех вопросов, на который можно быстрее ответить, поставив эксперимент самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

Да.

```
function hideShadow(){
    var el = document.getElementById("shadow");
    el.style.boxShadow = "0 0 0 0";
    el.style.textShadow = "0 0 0 0";
}
```